Tesseract 5 within EMGU exception when initialising with tesseract method
Using Tesseract within EMGU, a Tesseract object
Emgu.CV.OCR.Tesseract

is created. Then on initialisation Init(dataPath As String, language As String, mode As Emgu.CV.OCR.OcrEngineMode), three parameters are

Path to  the training data
Language
Engine mode

Of parameter 3, engine mode, the options in the enumeration are
 Emgu.CV.OCR.OcrEngineMode.TesseractOnly = 0
 Emgu.CV.OCR.OcrEngineMode.LstmOnly = 1
 Emgu.CV.OCR.OcrEngineMode.TesseractLstmCombined = 2
 Emgu.CV.OCR.OcrEngineMode.Default = 3

Options 0, 2 and 3 involve the tesseract method, and on initialisation, throw the exception
System.ArgumentException: 'Unable to create ocr model using Path 'tessdata-fast', language 'eng' and OcrEngineMode 'TesseractOnly'.'

Why is this the case, why can I only use the neural network model?

The legacy engine (Tesseract) components are present only in models from this location, marked main. Models marked fast and best have only LSTM (neural network) components, and will cause initialisation of the legacy engine to fail.

So LSTM is Legacy and the Tesseract method is current? Where do I get the data for the current method, I've looked everywhere.

I have not clue what you mean by current method. TesseractOnly is legacy engine,  LstmOnly is "new" engine. Link models traineddata I already provided.

In your answer, you suggest the 'fast' and 'best' tessdata files only have components relating to the neural network model, which you have linked to the term LSTM, which you have called legacy. If one thing is legacy i.e. not current, its counterpart, Tesseract,  must be current. However in your comment you're saying the Tesseract method is legacy, and therefor that LSTM is current. Which is true?

I never call LSTM as legacy. Read my response carefully.  In rest of answer I tried to match engines to Emgu naming.
